# Multiply for Hours by Rate

Tags: mysql

I have data stored in the database as follows.

```
Hours           Rate
02:37:37         8.00
```

I have written a query like below

```
select (hours * rate) as pay from user_hours;
```

I am getting results as "16" which is not correct.

How can I get the correct result?

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: what data type is `Hours`?

Comment: Looks like `TIME` data type.

Comment: What's the correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really suggest storing the data in a time data type or in separate columns but here is a query that'll do it for you:

```
SELECT
   (SUBSTRING(hours,1,2) + SUBSTRING(hours,4,2)/60 + SUBSTRING(hours,7,2)/3600) * rate AS pay
FROM user_hours;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
02(your hour value) * 8.00 = 16
2 * 8 = 16
```

You are getting the right result.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are storing the "hours" as a string, so the string is `'02:37:37'`.  When MySQL encounters a string in a numeric context (such as for addition or multiplication), it converts the string to a number.  It takes the maximum number of leading characters that represent a number.  In this case that is `'02'`.

So, the answer is correct.

If you want to do the conversion as a time, you need something like:

```
select ((left(hours, 2) + 0) + (substring(hours, 3, 2) + 0) / 60.0 +
        (right(hours, 2) + 0) / (60.0 * 60.0)
       ) * rate;
```